# Adding one more column in the first row in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have this file in the format

```
0 -1.6
1  country -3.2
2  city    -2.1
```

So I want to sort by score which is the last column (-1.6,-3.2,-2.1). The labels are actually numbers between 0 and 100000(I just gave sample 0,1,2) However, I cannot use sort command directly because first row does not have a label. I wanted to insert the label 'constant' there and then sort by the score. How can insert the column 'constant' using awk or any other unix tool?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print $1, "constant", $2; next } 1' file | sort -k3,3n
```

That should insert the word "constant" in the middle of the first line, and print all other lines unmodified, then pass everything to `sort`, which should do a numeric ordering on the third field.

Comment: This solution do print the first line modified, then it prints it unmodified, so you get two version of first line.  You could do what I did, or `awk 'NR==1 { print $1, "constant", $2 ; next } 1'`

Comment: Added a `next` directive to skip to the next line, which I forgot the first time around...

Comment: That is why I normal give the output of the command in my post.

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple like this? Checks col $2 for the presence of a number using regex

```
awk '{if($2 ~ /[0-9]/)print $1,"CONSTANT",$2; else print $1,$2,$3}' file | sort -k3
```

Comment: Yankee  thanks but my labels can be between 1 and 100000, so this command only works for labels between (0,9)

Comment: thats not the case actually, its just looking for a digit, not just (0,9)

Answer (score -1):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk 'NR==1 {$1=$1 "  constant"} 1' file | sort -k3
0  constant -1.6
2  city    -2.1
1  country -3.2
```

Comment: Jotne, thanks but my labels can be between 1 and 100000, so this command only works for labels between (0,9)

Comment: @vkaul11 Note that command is looking at `$2`, not `$1` - and it should match any string that *contains* at least one digit - it's not restricted to a single-digit string.